# Installing Ubuntu on Oracle VM Virtual Box: Failed to open the optical disk file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I need to install Ubuntu 64-bit on Windows 7 64-bit using Oracle VM Virtual Box.

I downloaded Ubuntu Desktop iso file, opened the settings of VM and selected the disk image of Ubuntu.

After this the following error message appears. How to solve this issue?

UPDATE: I tried both 34-bit and 64-bit Ubunto. Both fail.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your ISO is broken or you selected the wrong OS when creating the virtual machine. Try to redownload the file from the Ubuntu home page and mount it again.

You can follow the steps from [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox). Eventhough its for Ubuntu 14.04, the steps will not change.